# Makefile: Running a specific target in parallel

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing, dependencies, target

I am learning Makefile and trying to implement parallelism. I am aware of the "-j" option. However, for example having the following makefile (on Windows)-

```
all: a b c d

a: 
 # some build rule

b:
 # some build rule with parallelism

c:
 # some build rule

d:
 #some build rule
```

I am trying to run `make all` with only target "b" running in parallel. Passing the -j option with the build rule for "b" doesn't work. Any pointers?

Comment: I assume you're using GNU make since it provides the `-j` option (this is not part of the POSIX definition of make).  GNU make provides no way to control which jobs are allowed to run in parallel other than prerequisites.  So if you don't want `a` and `c` to run in parallel you have to declare a dependency relationship such as `a: c`.  You might look into order-only rules if you don't want a rebuild of `c` to force a rebuild of `a`.

Comment: I don't mean to sleaze this all up, but in a pinch, you could `make serialPrereqTargets && make -j 8 parallelTargets`. This is unlikely to win awards with the parallel computing crowd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get b's recipe to run in the background as so:

```
all: a b c d
        @echo running $@

.PHONY: a b c d all

a c d: | b
        @echo -n _$@0 && \
         sleep 1 && echo -n _$@1 && \
         sleep 1 && echo _$@2

b:
        @(echo -n _$@0 && \
          sleep 2 && echo -n _$@1 && \
          sleep 2 && echo -n _$@2\
         ) &
```

Which outputs:

```
_b0_a0_a1_b1_a2
_c0_c1_b2_c2
_d0_d1_d2
running all
```

The order-only dependency on `b` makes `b` run first, otherwise it wouldn't start until after `a` completes with `-j1`...   It does of course mean that you have to build `b` if you build either `a` `c` or `d`.

Alternatively, (and I'm not recommending this) you could use some manual locking mechanism such as [flock](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) to prevent a, c, and d from running in parallel (note that the flock only protects a single shell, so you would have to collapse your recipes into a single line protected by flock for this to work).

Comment: I'm having a similar issue to the original poster's.  This answer doesn't fix my issue, but it does provide valuable insight into partial parallelism.  And I'd agree that if one is heading down the `flock` path, it's probably the wrong path.  +1